# If I kill Playboy X and get his penthouse, will I still have access to the safehouse in Bohan?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

Or at least will my cars parked at my Bohan safehouse still be accessible? I barely managed to get a car from Hove Beach to Bohan, it would be annoying if I lost it in the end...

EDIT: Killed Playboy, thankfully I appear to have access to PB's penthouse, the Bohan safehouse, and another safehouse in the middle island.

Answer (score 1):

Even if OP know what happened after [The Holland Play](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Holland_Play), I will explain what will happen with the [Broker](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Broker_Safehouse) and [South Bohan](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/South_Bohan_Safehouse) safe houses.

The first one will be the only that you will loose during the game history, but you still be able to use the parking space. During [Roman's Sorrow](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Roman%27s_Sorrow), Dimitri's people burned down the place with Molotov's.

In the case of the second one, is an optional safe house that will require you to kill Playboy X during [The Holland Play](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Holland_Play). After the mission, Dwayne will call you and Niko will explain what happened with Playboy. He will say that you should keep the apartment because the "place will makes him remind the boy a lot".

The rest of the safe houses will be unlocked after certain progress in the main history.